# Exec call to mkdir failing

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a program for an assignment, and I'm having problems with part of it where I am supposed to fork, use exec() to run mkdir to make a directory if it doesn't exist. I have 2 separate functions that are to have this functionality. It works with the first function, however the second function it always gets the error Bad Address. I'm not sure why this is happening, as it seems to me, as far as my understanding of local variables and what not that it should work. For clarification, 'new' is a desired path given in the command line.

If anyone has any ideas on what the problem might be that would be swell. (code below)

```
if(chdir(new) == -1)    //check if desired directory exists, if not create
{
   pid_t pid = fork();
   char **args;

   if((args = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2)) == NULL)
   {
      perror("args malloc() failed!");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if(pid == 0)
   {

      args[0] = "mkdir";
      args[1] = new;
      if(execv("/bin/mkdir", args) == -1)
      {
         perror("mkdir failed!");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   }
   else if(pid > 0)
   {
      wait(NULL);
      for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)    //free each value of args
      {
         free(args[i]);
      }
      free(args);           //free args
   }
}
```

Comment: `mkdir` is basically a wrapper around a system call that you should be calling directly, rather than forking a new process.

Comment: @chepner Sounds like the assignment requires it to be done this way rather than just using the system call.

Comment: You only `malloc` the array `args` and not the contents of the pointers it holds.  I would think `free(args[i]);` will be a problem as those are not allocated on the heap.

Comment: Please post the output of `perror("mkdir failed!");`.

Comment: Also I don't think you are using `execv` correctly.  First argument should be the path to the file you wish to run, and second argument should be an array of args (which I suspect "mkdir" should not be among them since that is handled by the path) which should have a the final element be a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: I was confused for a bit because the page highlighted `new` even though this is C.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons You do in fact have to put the name of the executable in both the 'path' argument and the 'argv' argument.  This is because you're allowed to invoke a program and give it an argv[0] different than the name of its image file on disk.

Comment: According to the `execv` manual page, regarding `args`: *The array of pointers must be terminated by a null pointer.*. So you must have an `args[2] = NULL` (and, of course, `args` must have space to hold 3 pointers, not two).

Comment: @zwol Ah.  The man page wasn't very clear on that point.

Comment: Alternatively, use the `l` version instead of the `v` version:  `execl("/bin/mkdir", "mkdir", new, NULL);`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. Not used to using this whole Malloc thing yet haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few bugs in your code

- `args` is double pointer of char type, you allocated memory only for `args`, should allocate for `args[0]` and `args[1]` also, then only you can do `args[0] = "mkdir";`
- I suggest to to take array of char pointer( `char *args[NUM]`) instead of doubler pointer(`char **args`).

Here is the complete code which helps you

```
int main() {
        /* take array of char pointer & store into it what you want to execute using execv */
        char *args[] = {"/bin/mkdir","mkdir","/home/achal/s_flow1",NULL};
        if(chdir(args[2]) == -1) {   //check if desired directory exists, if not create
                int pid = fork();
                if(pid == 0) { /* args+1  is amazing if you understand */
                        if(execv(args[0],args+1) == -1) {
                                perror("mkdir failed!");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }
                }
                else if(pid > 0) {
                        wait(NULL);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you `fork`, you get two seperate processes (the parent and the child), each with its own memory, with its own copy of everything in the memory.  Since you `fork` after calling `malloc` the malloced memory is duplicated, and subsequent assignments to that memory in one process do not affect the memory in the other process.

So when you assign values to `args[0]` and `args[1]` in the child, those elements in the parent are unaffected; they're still uninitialized.  Then in the parent, when you free `args[0]` and `args[1]` you get undefined behavior, as those are uninitialized pointers.

The easiest fix is to move the malloc call entirely into the child (after the fork) -- then you don't need to worry about it in the parent at all.  You also don't need to worry about freeing things in the child (you currently don't) as all the memory is automatically released on calling `exec`

Even better, don't use malloc at all -- just use a local (auto on stack) array in the child:

```
if (pid == 0) {
    char *args[] = { "mkdir", new, 0 };  // need a null pointer to mark the end of the arg list
    execve("/bin/mkdir", args);
    perrer("execve failed!")    // if execve returns, it failed -- don't actually need to check the error code
```